# Checkbox append text to string if checked then write either empty string or appended string on button press

Tags: android, android-activity, android-checkbox

Trying to get my app to have a funtional multiple choice option where any of the checkboxes will append the name of the checkbox if checked to a string that will ultimatly be logged to txt file. Otherwise if any of the checkboxes are unchecked nothing will be appended.

```
    //Checkbox onclick actions
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) 
{
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.fortunetellingCheckBox1:
            if (checked)
            distortions.append("Fortune-Telling");
            break;
        case R.id.mindreadingCheckBox2:
            if (checked)
            // Append "Mind-Reading" to String distortions
            break;
            // TODO:
    }

    btnWriteSDFile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // write on SD card file data in the text box
                try {
                    File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mythoughtlog.txt");
                    myFile.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);
                    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                        new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    myOutWriter.append(txtData.getText());
                    myOutWriter.append('\n');
                    myOutWriter.append(situation.getText());
                    myOutWriter.append('\n');
                    myOutWriter.append(thoughts.getText());
                    myOutWriter.append('\n');
                    myOutWriter.append(emotions.getText());
                    myOutWriter.append('\n');
                    myOutWriter.append(behavior.getText());
                    myOutWriter.append('\n');
                    myOutWriter.append(distortions);
                    myOutWriter.append('\n');
                    myOutWriter.append(altbehavior.getText());
                    myOutWriter.append('\n');
                    myOutWriter.append(altthoughts.getText());
                    myOutWriter.append('\n');
                    myOutWriter.close();
                    fOut.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have the CheckBoxes working as the code looks like will work. I will warn you that how you currently have it you will be appending the text every that you check and uncheck the checkBox as the append is never undone. I believe your current code was not working because you never actually called the print command for the FileOutStream so you added data but never printed it

For writing to the SD card couple of things that I would recommend(In code below). Instead of using the OutStreamWriter use a **StringBuffer** for appending the text to and a **PrintStream** to write to file as this allows to write Strings to the file. It's also poor practice to hardcode where the SD card is and you should use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() rather than "/sdcard"

Also please make sure that you have the permission set to write to file in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Example of what I described above

```
public void writeToFile(View view) {
    try {
        // Use getExternalStorage to make sure that you are using the correct directory. You never want to hardcode the storage directory
        File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File myFile = new File(directory, "mythoughtlog.txt");

        // Check if the file already exists so you don't keep creating
        if(!myFile.exists()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Creating the file as it doesn't exist already");
            myFile.createNewFile();
        }

        // Open the FileoutputStream
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);

        // Open the printStream to allow for Strings to be written
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(fOut);

        // Using a stringBuffer to append all the values to
        // TODO add your code for appending here
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        stringBuffer.append("String 1");
        stringBuffer.append("String 2");
        stringBuffer.append("String 3");

        // Print the stringBuffer to the file
        printStream.print(stringBuffer.toString());

        // Close everything out
        printStream.close();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: My code currently crashes when I click the fortunetelling checkbox.